# longitudinal dataset categorical variables

Tags: stata

I have a longitudinal dataset which contains variables on individuals from 2 waves from Feb and June which measure economic activity across these individuals. The  variables from Feb and May wave are categorical variables and I am running the `proportion` command in Stata to get the individual change in  economic  activity. For example. I am looking for changes in hours worked across 2 waves and I run `proportion` but am not able to figure out the `if` condition as I only want individuals who responded in both Feb and June. I want to drop all those who responded in Feb but not in May or likewise.

Comment: May or June? The story isn't straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you have an identifier variable `id` and a time-like variable, `wave` that takes values 1 and 2. If so, you are looking for individuals that satisfy

```
bysort id (wave) : gen wanted = wave[1] == 1 & wave[2] == 2
```

So `wanted` is an indicator that is 1 for individuals present for both waves and 0 otherwise and `if wanted` would be an `if` condition to select those people wanted.

There are many variations on this, depending on: your variable names; your data layout; how the information on waves is held (could be also, say, a string variable containing values like `"Feb"`, `"May"` or `"June"`, or a numeric variable holding dates).

You gave a broad-brush description sketching the problem but almost no precise information on the data. The `stata` tag wiki gives much detailed advice on how to post a question and flags the importance of giving a concrete data example.